# How to use multiple lookup fields in Django Rest framework in a class based view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I literally searched similar questions but  didn't a answer that solves my question

I want a functionality like a question can have multiple answers

my models.py

```
class QuestionModel(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doubt_class_id = models.ForeignKey(DoubtClasses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    conceptual_class_id = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mentor = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def clean(self):
        if self.doubt_class_id and self.conceptual_class_id :
            raise ValidationError("only one field can be set")
    

class AnswersModel(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(QuestionModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my urls.py

```
path('questions/', views.QuestionModelView.as_view()),
path('questions/<int:id>/', views.QuestionModelViewID.as_view()),
path('questions/<int:id>/answer/', views.AnswerModel.as_view()),
```

my views.py

```
# Create your views here.

class QuestionModelView(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin,GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.QuestionModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.QuestionModel_serializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        return self.list(request)

    def post(self, request):
        return self.create(request)

class QuestionModelViewID(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin,GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.QuestionModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.QuestionModel_serializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, id=None):
        if id:
            return self.retrieve(request, id)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def put(self, request, id=None):
        if int(request.POST.get('author')) != self.request.user.id:
            return Response("you cannot edit othe user question", status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
        if id:
                return self.update(request, id)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        
        
    def delete(self, request, id=None):
        if int(request.POST.get('author')) != self.request.user.id:
            return Response("you cannot destroy othe user question", status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
        if id:
            return self.delete(request, id)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    
        



class AnswerModel(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, GenericAPIView):

    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = serializers.AnswerModel_serializer
   
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return models.AnswersModel.objects.filter(question_id = self.kwargs['id'])
    
    
    def get(self, request, id=None):
       return self.list(request)
      
    def post(self, request, id=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.create(request, id)
        else:
            return Response("only superuser can post a answer", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to make a url like questions/id/answers/answer_id where id is the question id and answer_id is the id for a particular answer as a question can have multiple answers but for that i want to add 2 lookup_fields in my view which i am not getting how to add it or please suggest another approach for this query  if its not possible to do like that

Comment: Django rest framework supports one lookup field by default. If you want more lookup fields try creating custom mixins like MultipleFieldLookupMixin:

 https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have query like this `questions/id/answers/answer_id`

you can do like this if I understood your question good.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
 answerid = self.kwargs['answer_id']
        queryset = Model.objects.get(
            id=id,answerid=answerid)
        return queryset

or 

def get(self, request, id, answer_id):
    Questiomn = Model.objects.get(
            id=id,answerid=answerid)
```